# Android: Is it possible, to create a List with an arrayAdapter, that is clickable and has a checkbox for each list item?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, listactivity, android-checkbox

I have a ListView that is clickable in a class(a new activity is opened, when you click on it), that extends ListActivity.This List get's filled through an arrayAdapter. Now I've tried to make the list checkable by implementing "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice" in the second Parameter of the ArrayAdapter Constructor. So the checkbox has arrived, but when I click on it, the activity is opened, but the checkbox isn't checked. To solve this issue, I`ve set the Parameters "focusable" and "focusableInTouchMode" of the ListLayout to false. But this hasn't worked either. I guess, that I have a problem with the focusable Parameter, but I think I have to change it anywhere else. But because the arrayAdapter takes away the work to define a layout for a single ListItem, I don't know where to do this. When I try to define a layout with a checkbox on my own, I get the error, that an ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID of the layout to be a TextView. So

1. Is it possible to solve this problem with an ArrayAdapter?
2. If yes, how can I solve it?

I appreciate your suggestions

Comment: Yes !! you can create custom layout file instead of android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice

Comment: When I create a custom layout file with a checkbox I get the Error message, that an ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID of the layout to be a TextView. Now i try to use the class "CheckedTextView" in my layout file. This one is accepted by the arrayAdapter. But actually i can't open my activity anymore, by clicking at the text left to the button...

Comment: Okay, I've solved the problem by checking the button via code in the class, when I click at a CheckedListView item. But I think, that the "optimal" solution, that you can open the activity by clickin on the text and toggling the button by clicking at the button isn't possible with arrayadapter...